# Jquery second Click Fire event missing first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, click, position

Firstly, click a link will be having a ajax call and once it is returned success, will call another function...

```
//First Call
$(this).click(ajaxHandler);

function ajaxHandler(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    var urlLink = someURL;
    var data = "id=" + "123";

    // Unbind the ajax handler to prevent re-fire before ajax request completes
    $obj.unbind("click", ajaxHandler);

    $.ajax({
        url: urlLink,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp){
            // Bind the new event handler
            $obj.bind("click", someFunction);

            // Fire click on Object
            $obj.click();
        },
        error: function(){
            // Put the ajax handler back so the user can try again if it fails
            $obj.bind("click", ajaxHandler);
        }
    });
}
```

Here, in "someFunction", I am calling like,

```
someFunction: function(e){
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
    var p = evt.target.name;
    var x = evt.pageX;
    var y = evt.pageY;
   ............
}
```

First time I am getting **evt.pageX** and **evt.pageY** is undefined. If I click on the link again, then giving the exact position.

I am getting data for **evt.target.name** for first time also.
These events are useful for tooltip.

Please, Help me how to identify the axis position for first time.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you miss when firing the first time, just keep shooting.

Comment: Any flaw in my code, why I am missing first time and not second time.

Comment: You're getting undefined for pageX on the first click to which someFunction is bound as an event handler (which would be the second click to the link)?

Comment: so, how can i make it identified that event should handle even in first time, Do I need to add any more calls before bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined the first time, because the click event is fired manually, not by the user clicking with the mouse. To work around it, you can call `someFunction` manually instead of triggering the event and you can pass the first call's event variable through.

```
//First Call
$(this).click(ajaxHandler);

function ajaxHandler(e){
    var $obj = $(this);
    var urlLink = someURL;
    var data = "id=" + "123";

    // Unbind the ajax handler to prevent re-fire before ajax request completes
    $obj.unbind("click", ajaxHandler);

    $.ajax({
        url: urlLink,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp){
            // Bind the new event handler
            $obj.bind("click", someFunction);

            // call function in the context of $obj and pass through event variable
            someFunction.apply($obj[0],[e]);
        },
        error: function(){
            // Put the ajax handler back so the user can try again if it fails
            $obj.bind("click", ajaxHandler);
        }
    });
}
```

In `someFunction` you don't have to do anything fancy with the event variable, jQuery normalises it for you:

```
someFunction: function(evt){
    var p = evt.target.name;
    var x = evt.pageX;
    var y = evt.pageY;
   ............
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, This is not firing the "someFunction" first time.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the `.apply()` call, you have to pass an array, not just a variable. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

i usually just keep track of it at all times on mousemove and it always works for me

```
var xPos;
var yPos;

$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {

    xPos = e.clientX;
    yPos = e.clientY;
});

});
```

or maybe do a delay like so
        `setTimeout(function () {$obj.click(); 
    }, 500);`

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response, This is in general solution to get the event position but I need to get the position of the anchor tag in someFunction, I am not passing the axis position from ajaxHandler.

Comment: maybe put a slight delay on the line $obj.click();

Answer (score 0):

try using the $obj.live("click", function()...)

I found it works better than bind